# Force user to see only single application window

Tags: 18.04, permissions, microk8s

I'd like to configure Ubuntu 18.04 system so that:

1. User, after logging in, can only use a single application and nothing else
2. Underneath other with access can connect via ssh and have full control of the PC
3. kubernetes cluster starts up automatically on user log in but user cannot access/view/control any of this.

As far as I've researched Ubuntu Kiosk gives me and option to do point No 1. But what I'm not clear on is whether it doesn't restrict other processes on the PC. We have a single PC that needs to display to user only one app, but at the same time run Kubernetes cluster which is connected to GPU and so on that user has no control over. Could somebody point me to what I should look at?

The purpose is to essentially give PC to a client with pre-installed software, that client cannot access but that the supplier can still modify, etc. (think something similar to an ATM)

Comment: This seems like exactly the use case for Ubuntu Core (instead of Ubuntu Server).

Comment: This should all be run on a PC - not a virtual server or anything else. This all should be run on a full PC as it is connected to various hardware that is used (Cameras, sensors etc) as well as fully uses GPU and CPU resources. As far as I've researched Ubuntu Core is designed only for embedded systems, no?

Comment: You seem to be describing a (large) embedded system. Ubuntu Core will happily run on a PC or in a VM or on a RPi, GPU or no-GPU...just like Ubuntu Server will. Obviously, you can reject Ubuntu Core for any reason (or no reason) and stick to Ubuntu Server -- it's YOUR project. Just thought you should know.